# subdomain won't resolve with my bind

Tags: centos, bind

I have domain hosted here in cloudflare, while it is hosted there I am using a nameserver IP address(`/etc/resolv.conf` on linux) on my machine with my own bind server IP address. all is actually fine and working.

I am able to ping my domain and everything. but when I setup a subdomain there is a problem with pinging the subdomain url within its network. I can’t ping my subdomain inside my subdomain server or anywhere inside my network of the same IP block of my subdomain.

- `ping domain.com` (works inside and out of my own network using my own bind server)
- `ping sub.domain.com` (doesn't work inside, but work outside of my own network using my own bind server)

Both domain.com and sub.domain.com can be ping from the outside of my network, but sub.domain.com is not pingable inside my network if I use my own bind server.

While using google dns on my `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

This works when I ping my domain.com and sub.domain.com from either inside or outside of my network. I can ping the domain and sub.domain with this on my resolve.conf

My personal bind server works and serve some of my other domain with subdomain as well. If I use google dns I am able to ping it. This only happen to my new domain. I can ping the domain.com but not sub.domain.com within my own network, but can be ping outside.

I also find out that my bind server can't ping my sub.domain.com which dns record is in cloudflare.

Any suggestion on where to look at? I'm not sure if there is needed to be done with the domain registrar or if I made a mistake with the settings somewhere. This is only happening right now with my 2 new domain.

Comment: Does "_can't ping_" mean you can't resolve the name, or that you can resolve the name to an IP address but that you don't get replies from the IP address?

Comment: ping sub.domain.com "doesnt work its not resolving"
ping domain.com "works"
ping IP.address.of.subdomain "work"

doing ping do sub.domain.com will work only if I use google dns on its resolve.conf

Comment: Please would you add that clarification to your question so it's easy to read.

Comment: You keep writing `/etc/resolve.conf`. You do know it should be `/etc/resolv.conf` don't you (without the `e`).

Comment: You still don't seem to have answered my question at the top of the comments...??

Comment: can't resolve the name

Comment: In that case the only answer I can give you with the information you've provided is that your internal DNS is at fault.